# jQuery 1.8.0 - appendTo() does not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a `<table>` with `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. Now in `$(document).ready()` I have a function targeting that `<tbody>` and make an ajax call to a servlet. The resulting `Json` will then be inserted into the tbody row-by-row and cell-by-cell.

The following is a code fragment.

```
    var tbody = $('#topten');
    $.each(responseJson, function(i, obj) {

        var trkey = $('<tr>');
        trkey.appendTo(tbody);

        $.each(obj, function(K, V) {
            if (K == 'abc') {
                var td = $('<td>');
                td.appendTo(trkey);
            }

       });

    });
```

I got the following exception from IE8 console:

```
SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
jquery-1.8.0.js, line 5565 character 5
```

which happens to be

```
this.appendChild( elem );
```

My app works perfectly in IE9,10 FF, Chrome...but just not IE8.

May I ask if there's work around for this issue?

Thanks

**EDIT: Realized that it was the input box that I appendTo() into the td that caused the problem, this code fragment is fine. So the question is closed. Apologize.**

Comment: looks like your trkey has incorrect value which IE is not liking.

Comment: Why are you using `.val()`? If you're trying to set the content of an element, use `.text()` or `.html()`.

Comment: Does it help if you move `trkey.appendTo(tbody);` to **after** the `$.each()`?

Comment: What version of jQuery ?

Comment: @adeneo, read the title

Comment: @AtesGoral I removed the all .val() statements, still not working though.

Comment: @jmoerdyk - Ooops, really seem to be having trouble reading today !

Comment: @Ian sorry forgot to reply, there's no difference...

Comment: This works fine in IE 8: http://jsfiddle.net/UmySV/1/ . To view it in IE 8, visit http://jsfiddle.net/UmySV/1/show/ and you don't get any errors.

Comment: @hydrology thanks a lot...ur edit about appending to input was a pointer to me...been fighting with this all day, finally solved it! thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 1):

**FYI:** *IE8, IE7 and IE6 will not allow any modification to that element, including* `.append()` and `.appendTo()` *because they are not considered standard or correct DOM elements, and hence are treated as **text**. Make sure that you close your elements such as `<div></div><a></a>`, etc. so the older browsers can tell what you are trying to do.*

[Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfWzR/1/)

**Description:**

`.appendTo()` *works great if you pass a DOM element created with the new window. But fail if created from original window (html string or created with $() just before).*

Comment: is there any workaround for this? Other than create a new window?

Comment: `because they are not considered standard or correct DOM elements, and hence are treated as text. ` - what are you talking about? None of this makes sense. Nothing's being treated as text; everything is using jQuery objects

Comment: @Ian _when you create elements in the DOM, if they are not closed, IE8, IE7 and IE6 will not allow any modification to that element, including_ `.append()` and `.appendTo()`, i am  talking about that they

Comment: @DKM But where do you see elements not being closed?

Comment: @Ian not talking about the markup mentioned in post, may be this could be link with the other tags.

Comment: @Ian - you nailed it, this makes no sense at all ?

Comment: @Ian I just given the suggestion or information, i don't exactly know what markup is there, just assuming these cases can be there :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to only hit the DOM only once redefining this section:

```
var trkey = '<tr>';
$.each(obj, function (K, V) {
    if (K == 'abc') {
        trkey = trkey + '<td></td>';
    }
});
trkey = trkey + '</tr>';
$(trkey).appendTo(tbody);
```